# Download image to tableview from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
class ArtistModel {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var genre: String?
    var img: String?

    init(id: String?, name: String?, genre: String?, img: String?){
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
        self.img = img
    }
}
```

and this my tableviewCell

```
class addArtistTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblGenre: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
```

and this my viewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class addArtistViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     var refArtists: FIRDatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldGenre: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewArtists: UITableView!

    //list to store all the artist
    var artistList = [ArtistModel]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //getting the selected artist
        let artist  = artistList[indexPath.row]

        //building an alert
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: artist.name, message: "Give new values to update ", preferredStyle: .alert)

        //the confirm action taking the inputs
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default) { (_) in

            //getting artist id
            let id = artist.id

            //getting new values
            let name = alertController.textFields?[0].text
            let genre = alertController.textFields?[1].text

            //calling the update method to update artist
            self.updateArtist(id: id!, name: name!, genre: genre!)
        }

        //the cancel action doing nothing
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

        //adding two textfields to alert
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = artist.name
        }
        alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.text = artist.genre
        }

        //adding action
        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        //presenting dialog
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return artistList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        //creating a cell using the custom class
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! addArtistTableViewCell

        //the artist object
        let artist: ArtistModel

        //getting the artist of selected position
        artist = artistList[indexPath.row]

        //adding values to labels
        cell.lblName.text = artist.name
        cell.lblGenre.text = artist.genre

        //returning cell
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAddArtist(_ sender: UIButton) {

        addArtist()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





        //getting a reference to the node artists
        refArtists = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("artists")

        //observing the data changes
        refArtists.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //if the reference have some values
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                //clearing the list
                self.artistList.removeAll()

                //iterating through all the values
                for artists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    //getting values
                    let artistObject = artists.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let artistName  = artistObject?["artistName"]
                    let artistId  = artistObject?["id"]
                    let artistGenre = artistObject?["artistGenre"]
                    let artistImg = artistObject?["artistImg"]

                    //creating artist object with model and fetched values
                    let artist = ArtistModel(id: artistId as! String?, name: artistName as! String?, genre: artistGenre as! String?, img: artistImg as! String?)

                    //appending it to list
                    self.artistList.append(artist)
                }

                //reloading the tableview
                self.tableViewArtists.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }


    func addArtist(){
        //generating a new key inside artists node
        //and also getting the generated key
        let key = refArtists.childByAutoId().key

        //creating artist with the given values
        let artist = ["id":key,
                      "artistName": textFieldName.text! as String,
                      "artistGenre": textFieldGenre.text! as String,
                      ] //as [String : Any]

        //adding the artist inside the generated unique key
        refArtists.child(key).setValue(artist)

        //displaying message
        labelMessage.text = "Artist Added"
    }

    func updateArtist(id:String, name:String, genre:String){
        //creating artist with the new given values
        let artist = ["id":id,
                      "artistName": name,
                      "artistGenre": genre
        ]

        //updating the artist using the key of the artist
        refArtists.child(id).setValue(artist)

        //displaying message
        labelMessage.text = "Artist Updated"
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question here? What section of code isn't working or what are you stuck on? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry about that i need to add photo to my cell by firebase that's all

Comment: What's causing the issue? The getting started guide shows how to download an image from Firebase storage into memory. From there just add it to the array you are using as the tableView datasource. See [Download Files in iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files).

Answer (score 0):

First I'd cache the image.

```
    let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageFromCacheWithUrlSting(urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

This will save you downloading the image every time the view loads. Then add something like this to cellForRow

```
if let artistImage = dictionary["img"] as? String {
cell?.artistImageView.loadImageFromCacheWithUrlSting(urlString: artistImage)
}
```

Comment: set all in addArtistViewController ?

Comment: This doesn't address the question - the OP wants to know how to *Download image to tableview from Firebase*